# ruby inserts null values to mysql table

Tags: mysql, ruby, encoding

I am using the MySQL gem in order to write values to a MySQL table. The table has 2 fields:  one is `int` and the other is `text`. However, when I write data (using Ruby MySQL gem) into the table, the text shows up as NULL. Any ideas?

My ruby code:

```
insert_new = db.prepare "INSERT INTO keywords (id, name) VALUES (?,?)"
insert_new.execute i, element.text.to_s
```

Comment: you absolutely positive about `element.text.to_s` not being null when calling insert_new? (like print the value on standard out before calling insert_new)

Comment: yes, did that. BTW - i tried to insert it without .to_s first. Same results. Thanks

Comment: what happens if you do: `db.prepare("INSERT INTO keywords (id, name) VALUES (3, 'test')").execute`

Comment: That works fine. The problem is with the prepared statements probably